# Multiple Interpreters with login

Tags: php, syntax, jquery-terminal

I am attempting to get a multi-interpreter set up and working and running into a bit of an issue, specifically utilizing an external login source.

First off, the snippet I'm using to setup the terminal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var term = $('#content').terminal('terminal/process.php', {
    login: true,
    onExit: function(terminal) { terminal.clear(); },
    prompt: '>',
    completion: true,
    greetings: '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nTerminal\n\n\n\n\n\n\n',
    height: 320,
    width: 560
  });
});
```

Now the login piece works as designed. However, I'd like to add multiple interpreters while retaining the required login at launch. If I tweak the http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#multiple_interpreters to look like

```
}, {
  login: true,
  greetings: "multiply terminals demo use help"+
        " to see available commands"
});});
```

It throws an error 'Authenticate must be a function'.

I'm looking for any advice on the best way to set this up, be it writing a login function, tweaking how the initial terminal is created, or something completely different. The end goal is trying to emulate a Cisco type terminal with two runtime levels with the option to change the prompt in both run levels based on various command input.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple terminals but terminal/process.php have login as JSON-RPC method then just call login by yourself:

```
{
   login: function(login, password, callback) {
     $.jrpc('terminal/process.php', 'login', [login, password], function(data) {
        callback(data.result);
     });
   },
   ...
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Is there any documentation available for $.jrpc on the site?